# Why does numpy.arange function start parameter actually determines stop?

Tags: python, numpy

I was reading the [numpy.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) documentation and wanted to try out a few things myself. (numpy version 1.14.5)

Here is my code:

```
print(np.arange(start=5))
```

I am not sure what my expectation was, but definitely not this:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
```

How should I read the documentation and the function signature, so that I understand what is going on here? Obviously `start` here is `0` and `stop` is `5`, but how does this work? Please note I am a beginner in Python so this might be my lack of knowledge on optional parameters on methods.

Comment: `arange` is, in ways, a `numpy` equivalent of Python `range`.  `range` doesn't take keyword arguments, just the 1-3 positional arguments.  `arange` is not a good function to explore the use of optional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.arange`'s signature is documented as `numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)`, indicating that `start` and `step` are optional, and that if one positional argument is provided, it'll be treated as `stop`... but in implementation, it's more like

```
def arange(start, stop=None, step=None, dtype=None):
    ...
```

I say "more like" because it's written in C and [the implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.5/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L2938) doesn't actually look like that, but it mostly works like that.

If `arange` receives one positional argument, it'll treat it as a stop value, but it'll still receive it as the `start` argument. To handle this, `arange` is coded so that if it receives a `start` and no `stop` or `step`, it'll treat the `start` as the stop value. Unfortunately, that still applies when it receives `start` by keyword, leading to the confusing situation you're in.

Comment: But how come `foo=5` leads to  `TypeError: Required argument 'start' (pos 1) not found ` ?

Comment: @KorayTugay: Because you didn't provide a `start` value, and `start` is required.

Comment: So I would not be terribly wrong to expect a `TypeError` with `start=5` if I had to guess what would be the outcome only by looking at the documentation?

Comment: @KorayTugay: From the docs, a `TypeError` would be a reasonable thing to expect.

Answer (score 0):

`np.arange` needs both a `start` and a `stop`. If you provide only one parameter it will be interpreted as `stop` and `start` will default to `0`. That's what's happening here.

The possible usages are:

```
np.arange(stop) # assumes start=0, step=1
np.arange(start, stop) # assumes step=1
np.arange(start, stop, step)
```

`np.arange(start)` would make no sense since there is no "meaningful default" number to stop...

Comment: How come when I try `foo=5` instead of `start=5` I get `TypeError: Required argument 'start' (pos 1) not found`?

Comment: Also `stop=5` will lead to `TypeError: Required argument 'start' (pos 1) not found` which is very confusing..

Comment: You need to read about how python deals with positional arguments, this is not C...

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I am not sure if your answer helps me. Thanks though.